# How to make a infinite cycling GridView(one row enabled)

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm using `AdaptiveGridView` with `OneRowEnabled` import from windows community toolkit, and found NetFlix app having an interesting thing. All the category items are infinite cycle, ie, when scrolling to the last item, and then the first item comes following the last item. It's like a circle list, the last one connect with the first one.

I think the picture may be more intuitive.

The Green area is user visible. When I scroll right, the items goes left. When scroll the last item, `item 100`, for example, the `item 1` follows to appear into the user visual area. It seems that item 100 and `item 1` are always seamless connected. This is fantastic.

So how to do like this, thx.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need actually is a looping list control. The telerik UI for UWP has a ready-made control 'LoopingList' control. It's now open source. You could check its source code: https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP/tree/master/Controls/Primitives/Primitives.UWP/LoopingList

You could use it directly in your code.

```
xmlns:telerikLoopingList="using:Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.LoopingList"

<telerikLoopingList:RadLoopingList x:Name="loopingList"/>
```

```
loopingList.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(0,100).ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for reminding this awesome control. But it doesn't meet my needs somehow. If the looping mechanism can apply to `AdaptiveGridView`, that would be great.

Comment: @Vincent If the ready-made LoopingList control doesn't meet your requirement, you would have to make your own 'LoopingList' control. You could refer to AdaptiveGridView and LoopingList control's source code to make a similar 'AdaptiveLoopingGridView' control by yourself.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems difficult for me. Hope the windows community team can write the looping extension.

Comment: @Vincent Please submit your ideas on [Windows Community Toolkit Github](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22feature+request%22).

Comment: OK, issue link is https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2932